# Error Loading Enclave: Couldn't open file with CreateFile()

Tags: c++, windows, sgx, enclave

I'm trying to write a simple SGX project for a start. So I have this main host application routine that I've pretty much copied from [Lars Richter's blog](http://ayeks.de/2016/01/Create-and-Execute-an-Intel-SGX-Enclave/):

```
#define ENCLAVE_FILE _T("Enclave.signed.dll")
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include "sgx_urts.h"
#include "Enclave_u.h"

int main()
{
    sgx_enclave_id_t   eid;
    sgx_status_t       ret = SGX_SUCCESS;
    sgx_launch_token_t token = { 0 };
    int updated = 0;

    ret = sgx_create_enclave(ENCLAVE_FILE, SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, &token, &updated, &eid, NULL);

    if (ret != SGX_SUCCESS) {
        printf("\nApp: error %#x, failed to create enclave.\n", ret);
    }


    scanf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine (I'm using the Intel C++ 17.0 compiler with Visual Studio 2015) but it doesn't load the enclave. I get the following error message:

```
[sgx_create_enclavew ..\urts\win\urts.cpp:195] Couldn't open file with CreateFile()

App: error 0x200f, failed to create enclave.
```

Comment: Does Enclave.signed.dll exist somewhere sgx_create_enclave would find it?

Comment: It's in the solution's debug folder.

Comment: And what makes you think that sgx_create_enclave (whatever that is) would find it there?

Comment: You're right! When VS's debugger runs a project, the current directory is the project's root folder, not the solutions's debug folder. VS 101, I guess ;-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *app_test_save* project setting. Under **Debugging**, change *working directory* to *$(SolutionDir)Debug*. This answer assumes that both projects *app_test_save* and *enclave_test_save* belong to the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil pointed out, sgx_create_enclave couldn't find the dll when the program was being run from within Visual Studio's debugger. It worked fine when I directly ran the executable in the "Debug" folder.

So a simple trick to make it work in both settings is to do the following:

```
#define ENCLAVE_FILE _T("../Debug/Enclave.signed.dll")
```

Comment: This solution will cause you problems elsewhere because it assumes the DLL will always be relative to the working directory. For example the program could be run from root of C: as `c:\Users\user\program` and the dll will be looked for in `c:\..\Debug`, a directory that cannot exist.

Comment: Understandable, but these answers are meant to be read by others, and those others need to be aware that this solution is likely unusable in their case.

Answer (score 0):

According to this : https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-software-guard-extensions-intel-sgx/topic/623738

If you are using the Local SGX Debugger, Please make sure change the "current working directory" pointing to $(OutDir) instead of $(ProjectDir).

Configuration Properties --> Debugging --> Working Directory --> $(OutDir).

Answer (score 0):

Error is basically means it could not locate your .dll file.
Do dir /a/s to find Enclave.signed.dll then change the name appropriately.
When you create enclave it will generate signed.dll file. If your enclave name is Enclave12 then the DLL name is Enclave12.signed.dll. You fix this then you should be good to go.