# Cannot create Enclave in SGX Helloworld

Tags: sgx, enclave

Why "[sgx_create_enclavew ..\urts\win\urts.cpp:195] Couldn't open file with CreateFile()" still happens after I setting the working directory from $(ProjectDir) to $(OutDir) both enclave and app?

I cannot find the file "sample_enclave.signed.dll" in my VS working directory.

I followed this tutorial: https://software.intel.com/zh-cn/SGX-Development-Guide-Part-2

I use "VS 2015 Pro" and "SGX SDK 1.7" .

Comment: This is question is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41944179

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the project under "Debug" mode